# How do I Filter ListView in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview, filter

I have a ListView bound to a collection of items. I do not want to show the items where the property IsDeleted = "1". How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd use a CollectionView and set the Filter property to an expression:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefault(GetData());
view.Filter = i => ((MyType)i).IsDeleted != 1;
MyListView.DataSource = view;
```

Comment: +1, but you need to cast the parameter because `Filter` is of type `Predicate<object>`

Comment: What is the correct paradigm to do this, if I want to follow the MVVM design patter? I think view is a View thing, while the predicate (i=>IsDeleted) is a View Model thing. How would you sort it out?

Comment: @Uri - ICollectionView is a view model construct, in all my experiences of MVVM.