# Show only allowed data in WPF Listbox Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I currently have a list box:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=bookingDomainDataSource}"
         Margin="158,134,0,45"
         x:Name="bookingListBox"
         Width="429"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=bookingComboBox}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=userId}"
                           Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=bookingName}"
                           Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=bookingDate}"
                           Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=showId}"
                           Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=paymentId}"
                           Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ticketId}"
                           Width="100" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ticketQuantity}"
                           Width="100" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And I would like to only show rows from the `itemssource` that have a certain `userId`, how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution to this would be to filter the data source BEFORE you get to the front end.

Comment: How would I go about filtering the data, I am using WCF RIA Services

Comment: I'm not sure about your situation, but wherever you are making the call to the web services, be it in the code behind or a ViewModel, add something similar to:
bookingDomainDataSource = from b in bookingDomainDataSource
    where b.UserID == [valuehere]
    select b;

Comment: what you seem to have written does make sense but I can't get it to work. Would bookingDomainDataSource = from b in boo... work just like that?

Comment: Depends on your situation. Make sure you have "using System.Linq" at the top and bookingDomainDataSource is an enumerable object. I'd suggest doing some light reading on "linq to objects".

Comment: I've managed to figure it out, I had used: EntityQuery<Web.Booking>

Answer (score 0):

You want to [define a filter for your listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008481/how-do-i-filter-listview-in-wpf).

**Uodate**: sorry missed the silverlight tag. However `CollectionViewSource` should still be useful to you. Here a sample [using the `CollectionViewSource` in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2009/07/18/Use-CollectionViewSource-effectively-in-MVVM-applications.aspx).

Comment: The example you posted to doesn't seem to work in my silverlight application. GetDefault can't be used as it doesn't exist. I am using system.windows.data